# How to receive body attachment with application-json content type and boundary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

Our API should replace someone else API without many changes because of clients, but previous API receiving data in some form which i cannot replicate in .net core. In this case ModelState isn't valid after all.

Please see client request.

We are using .net core 2.0 mvc

I've already tried accept body as IFormFile but without success because of application/json content type. Also I tried to accept body as FromForm attribute parameter but without success too.

**My controller:**

```
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [HttpPost("product/set")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct([FromBody]IEnumerable<CreateProductInput> input)
    {
        // Some code and returns.
    }
```

**CreateProductInput:**

```
   public class CreateProductInput
   {
       [Required]
       [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot exceed {1} characters")]
       public string id { get; set; }

       [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot exceed {1} characters")]
       public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

But client requests looks like this:

**Headers:**

```
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8; boundary=--------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Content-Length: 1931
```

**Body:**

```
     --------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     Content-Disposition: attachment; name="data_file"

     [
            {
                           "id": "A1",
                           "name": "AAA",

            }, {
                           "id": "A2",
                           "name": "BBB",

            }, {
                           "id": "A3",
                           "name": "CCC",
            }
      ]

      --------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--
```

Is it possible to receive this kind of json attachment with `application/json` content type and how?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly, but that looks like `multipart/form-data`. You can potentially bind it via `FromForm` and treat it as a file upload(s) (`IFormFile`), Or, you can manually parse the request body and handle it however you want. Although this bit of documentation is geared towards handling large file uploads, the same principles in the code would apply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#uploading-large-files-with-streaming.